# blender camera structure - object inside the camera

Tags: camera

is it normal that the object has been inside the camera when I zoom in on the camera view? but the camera view is fine. thanks in advance! [image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is perfectly normal. The camera object is just a representation of it. If you don't like that, or it gets in the way in a more complex scene, you can just scale the camera object down with regular <kbd>s</kbd> hotkey for scale or adjust the viewport display size property in the Properties Editor:

[image]

The actual camera is not affected by this and is just a point at the origin of the camera object.